# Rest API jax-rs response shows multiple items in the json

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

I am building a simple REST API which returns a List of students on Get call.
And I am converting the List to standard Response provided by Jax-RS.
In the response, I see multiple items in Json. I am basically interested only in HttpStatus, Entity and Header.

**Controller**:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/allEnquiries")
    @ResponseBody
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getAllStudentEnquiry() {
        logger.info("Get all the student enquiry details");
        Response smsEnquiry = smsEnquiryService.getAllStudentEnquiry();
        return Response.ok(smsEnquiry).build();
    }
```

**Json Response:**

```
{
    "context": {
        "headers": {},
        "entity": {
            "context": {
                "headers": {},
                "entity": [
                    {
                        "eid": 15,
                        "fname": "Poshini",
                        "mname": "",
                        "lname": "AV",
                        "sgender": "Female",
                        "sage": "15",
                        "sclass": 10,
                        "father_name": null,
                        "mother_name": null,
                        "contact_number": 8109090908,
                        "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                        "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                        "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                        "van_facility": "yes",
                        "address": "Gulbarga",
                        "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                        "parent_queries": "",
                        "counsellor_name": "",
                        "enquiry_status": "",
                        "status_reason": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "eid": 16,
                        "fname": "Shubha",
                        "mname": "",
                        "lname": "AV",
                        "sgender": "Female",
                        "sage": "15",
                        "sclass": 10,
                        "father_name": null,
                        "mother_name": null,
                        "contact_number": 8109090908,
                        "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                        "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                        "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                        "van_facility": "yes",
                        "address": "Gulbarga",
                        "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                        "parent_queries": "",
                        "counsellor_name": "",
                        "enquiry_status": "",
                        "status_reason": ""
                    }
                ],
                "entityType": {
                    "actualTypeArguments": [
                        "com.ess.sms.enquiry.model.SmsEnquiry"
                    ],
                    "rawType": "java.util.List",
                    "ownerType": null,
                    "typeName": "java.util.List<com.ess.sms.enquiry.model.SmsEnquiry>"
                },
                "entityAnnotations": [],
                "entityStream": {
                    "closed": false,
                    "committed": false
                },
                "length": -1,
                "location": null,
                "language": null,
                "date": null,
                "lastModified": null,
                "mediaType": null,
                "links": [],
                "committed": false,
                "allowedMethods": [],
                "entityTag": null,
                "stringHeaders": {},
                "acceptableLanguages": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "acceptableMediaTypes": [
                    {
                        "type": "*",
                        "subtype": "*",
                        "parameters": {},
                        "quality": 1000,
                        "wildcardType": true,
                        "wildcardSubtype": true
                    }
                ],
                "requestCookies": {},
                "lengthLong": -1,
                "entityClass": "java.util.List",
                "responseCookies": {}
            },
            "status": 200,
            "length": -1,
            "location": null,
            "language": null,
            "date": null,
            "lastModified": null,
            "mediaType": null,
            "metadata": {},
            "links": [],
            "cookies": {},
            "allowedMethods": [],
            "statusInfo": "OK",
            "entityTag": null,
            "stringHeaders": {},
            "entity": [
                {
                    "eid": 15,
                    "fname": "Poshini",
                    "mname": "",
                    "lname": "AV",
                    "sgender": "Female",
                    "sage": "15",
                    "sclass": 10,
                    "father_name": null,
                    "mother_name": null,
                    "contact_number": 8109090908,
                    "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                    "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "van_facility": "yes",
                    "address": "Gulbarga",
                    "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                    "parent_queries": "",
                    "counsellor_name": "",
                    "enquiry_status": "",
                    "status_reason": ""
                },
                {
                    "eid": 16,
                    "fname": "Shubha",
                    "mname": "",
                    "lname": "AV",
                    "sgender": "Female",
                    "sage": "15",
                    "sclass": 10,
                    "father_name": null,
                    "mother_name": null,
                    "contact_number": 8109090908,
                    "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                    "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "van_facility": "yes",
                    "address": "Gulbarga",
                    "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                    "parent_queries": "",
                    "counsellor_name": "",
                    "enquiry_status": "",
                    "status_reason": ""
                }
            ],
            "headers": {}
        },
        "entityType": "org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse",
        "entityAnnotations": [],
        "entityStream": {
            "closed": false,
            "committed": false
        },
        "length": -1,
        "location": null,
        "language": null,
        "date": null,
        "lastModified": null,
        "mediaType": null,
        "links": [],
        "committed": false,
        "allowedMethods": [],
        "entityTag": null,
        "stringHeaders": {},
        "acceptableLanguages": [
            "*"
        ],
        "acceptableMediaTypes": [
            {
                "type": "*",
                "subtype": "*",
                "parameters": {},
                "quality": 1000,
                "wildcardType": true,
                "wildcardSubtype": true
            }
        ],
        "requestCookies": {},
        "lengthLong": -1,
        "entityClass": "org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse",
        "responseCookies": {}
    },
    "status": 200,
    "length": -1,
    "location": null,
    "language": null,
    "date": null,
    "lastModified": null,
    "mediaType": null,
    "metadata": {},
    "links": [],
    "cookies": {},
    "allowedMethods": [],
    "statusInfo": "OK",
    "entityTag": null,
    "stringHeaders": {},
    "entity": {
        "context": {
            "headers": {},
            "entity": [
                {
                    "eid": 15,
                    "fname": "Poshini",
                    "mname": "",
                    "lname": "AV",
                    "sgender": "Female",
                    "sage": "15",
                    "sclass": 10,
                    "father_name": null,
                    "mother_name": null,
                    "contact_number": 8109090908,
                    "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                    "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "van_facility": "yes",
                    "address": "Gulbarga",
                    "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                    "parent_queries": "",
                    "counsellor_name": "",
                    "enquiry_status": "",
                    "status_reason": ""
                },
                {
                    "eid": 16,
                    "fname": "Shubha",
                    "mname": "",
                    "lname": "AV",
                    "sgender": "Female",
                    "sage": "15",
                    "sclass": 10,
                    "father_name": null,
                    "mother_name": null,
                    "contact_number": 8109090908,
                    "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                    "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "van_facility": "yes",
                    "address": "Gulbarga",
                    "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                    "parent_queries": "",
                    "counsellor_name": "",
                    "enquiry_status": "",
                    "status_reason": ""
                }
            ],
            "entityType": {
                "actualTypeArguments": [
                    "com.ess.sms.enquiry.model.SmsEnquiry"
                ],
                "rawType": "java.util.List",
                "ownerType": null,
                "typeName": "java.util.List<com.ess.sms.enquiry.model.SmsEnquiry>"
            },
            "entityAnnotations": [],
            "entityStream": {
                "closed": false,
                "committed": false
            },
            "length": -1,
            "location": null,
            "language": null,
            "date": null,
            "lastModified": null,
            "mediaType": null,
            "links": [],
            "committed": false,
            "allowedMethods": [],
            "entityTag": null,
            "stringHeaders": {},
            "acceptableLanguages": [
                "*"
            ],
            "acceptableMediaTypes": [
                {
                    "type": "*",
                    "subtype": "*",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "quality": 1000,
                    "wildcardType": true,
                    "wildcardSubtype": true
                }
            ],
            "requestCookies": {},
            "lengthLong": -1,
            "entityClass": "java.util.List",
            "responseCookies": {}
        },
        "status": 200,
        "length": -1,
        "location": null,
        "language": null,
        "date": null,
        "lastModified": null,
        "mediaType": null,
        "metadata": {},
        "links": [],
        "cookies": {},
        "allowedMethods": [],
        "statusInfo": "OK",
        "entityTag": null,
        "stringHeaders": {},
        "entity": [
            {
                "eid": 15,
                "fname": "Poshini",
                "mname": "",
                "lname": "AV",
                "sgender": "Female",
                "sage": "15",
                "sclass": 10,
                "father_name": null,
                "mother_name": null,
                "contact_number": 8109090908,
                "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                "van_facility": "yes",
                "address": "Gulbarga",
                "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                "parent_queries": "",
                "counsellor_name": "",
                "enquiry_status": "",
                "status_reason": ""
            },
            {
                "eid": 16,
                "fname": "Shubha",
                "mname": "",
                "lname": "AV",
                "sgender": "Female",
                "sage": "15",
                "sclass": 10,
                "father_name": null,
                "mother_name": null,
                "contact_number": 8109090908,
                "student_dob": "2005-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                "emailid": "posh@gmail.com",
                "enquiry_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                "van_facility": "yes",
                "address": "Gulbarga",
                "enquiry_source": "Ad",
                "parent_queries": "",
                "counsellor_name": "",
                "enquiry_status": "",
                "status_reason": ""
            }
        ],
        "headers": {}
    },
    "headers": {}
}
```

**Basically I see my entity repeating in many places. Can I cut it short to just have my Json with HTTPStatus, Entity and HEaders. Am I missing something here? PS: Apologies for putting such huge response here.**

Comment: HI, your code is using a mixture of both JAX-RS and Spring MVC annotations. If you are using Spring MVC (which I believe you are), then you should completely remove the JAX-RS (Jersey) dependencies so you don't get confused about what you can and cannot use. These two _different_ frameworks are not compatible. And Just an FYI, if you are using Spring MVC, then the analogue of JAX-RS Response is Spring's [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Comment: Just so you understand, the JSON you are seeing, is the JAX-RS `Response` being serialized, not the entity of the Response. If you use Spring's `ResponeEntity`, you should get the result you are looking for. Also the `@Produces` does nothing as that is a JAX-RS annotation. For Spring, add a `produces` property in the `@GetMapping` annotation.

Comment: I apppreciate your response. I removed jax-rs framework and retained spring mvc. It worked :). Thanks!!!